# Why display :initial; is display :block ;when using flex but the default value of initial value is inline how it behaves?

Tags: css

From mdn i learned if property value is inherited by default then the propety tooks :root element means the propety tooks by default css value e.g
the propety of display is inline by default but when i give a parent display flex or display grid then the initial value of the child is display block how it behaves

```
    <div class="parent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, maxime?</p>
    </div>

    /* The result of p tag is block */
    .parent { display: flex; }
    p { display: initial; }

    /* The result of p tag is inline */
    p { display: initial; }
```

Comment: Not the _initial_ value. The initial value is "inline" in both cases. The _computed_ value of that p element when it is a flex item is "block".

Comment: why he tooks computed value when flex or grid but before he tooks inline how intial behaves do you explain me in clear words and easy to words then i can understand ?

Comment: `initial` never changes. `intial = inline` is **always** true for the `display` property.